# Stored Procedure For Updating Records And Deleting Records Using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that inserts records into the specified schema table using dynamic sql. To specify which schema you would like to insert into, it is done as follows:

```
EXEC Stored_Procedure_Name '[Schema_Name]', 'value1', 'value2', ...
```

The problem that I now face is that I wish to have a similar stored procedure that updates the table within a specified schema, as well as delete records within a specified schema's table, but I can't wrap my head around a method to accomplish this.

I've tried changing the code to make it `UPDATE` (instead of `INSERT INTO`) the tables but the logic behind it doesn't make any sense.

```
if object_id('AddUser_proc', 'AU') is not null
begin
    drop proc AddUser_proc;
end;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE AddUser_proc
    (@branch VARCHAR(50), 
     @UserID NUMERIC(13,0), 
     @Username VARCHAR(50), 
     @Email VARCHAR(50),
     @Fullname VARCHAR(100), 
     @Password BINARY(64),
     @DateCreated DATETIME,
     @ClosestBranch VARCHAR(50)    )
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Sys.Schemas
        WHERE name = @branch
    )
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @dynamic nvarchar(4000), 
            @paramDefinition nvarchar(4000)


        SELECT @dynamic = N'INSERT INTO '+ quotename(@branch) + N'.User_tbl (
            UserID,
            Username,
            Email,
            Fullname,
            Password,
            DateCreated,
            ClosestBranch
        )
        VALUES(@UserID, @Username, @Email, @Fullname, @Password, @DateCreated, @ClosestBranch)',
        @paramDefinition = 
          N'@UserID numeric(13,0), 
            @Username varchar(50), 
            @Email varchar(50), 
            @Fullname varchar(100), 
            @Password binary(64),
            @DateCreated datetime,
            @ClosestBranch varchar(50)'

        EXEC sp_executeSql  @dynamic, @paramDefinition, @UserID, @Username, @Email, @Fullname, @Password,
                            @DateCreated, @ClosestBranch;
    END
END
GO
```

Above is the code I have for the INSERT stored procedure. I would appreciate it if you could help me with a similar stored procedure that updates tables, as well as one that deletes records from tables. It would be ideal if all three (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) procedures could be contained within one stored procedure with the use of IF statements.

EDITED:

This is the SP that I have:

```sql
if object_id('UpdateUser_proc', 'UU') is not null
    begin
        drop proc UpdateUser_proc;
    end;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUser_proc(
    @branch varchar(50), 
    @UserID numeric(13,0), 
    @Username varchar(50), 
    @Email varchar(50),
    @Fullname varchar(100), 
    @Password binary(64),
    @DateCreated datetime,
    @ClosestBranch varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Sys.Schemas
        WHERE name = @branch
    )
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @dynamic nvarchar(4000), 
            @paramDefinition nvarchar(4000)


        SELECT @dynamic = N'UPDATE '+ quotename(@branch) + N'.User_tbl
        SET Username=@Username,Email=@Email,Fullname=@Fullname,Password=@Password,DateCreated=@DateCreated,ClosestBranch=@ClosestBranch
        WHERE UserID=@UserID',
        @paramDefinition = 
          N'@UserID numeric(13,0), 
            @Username varchar(50), 
            @Email varchar(50), 
            @Fullname varchar(100), 
            @Password binary(64),
            @DateCreated datetime,
            @ClosestBranch varchar(50)'

        EXEC sp_executeSql  @dynamic, @paramDefinition, @UserID, @Username, @Email, @Fullname, @Password,
                            @DateCreated, @ClosestBranch;
    END
END
GO
```

And I execute it like so:

```sql
EXEC UpdateUser_proc 'Bloemfontein', '7928623003512', 'klover', 'test.g@g.com', 'John Snow', 'password', '20190303', 'Bloemfontein'
```

I have discovered that the problem may be due to the fact that the password field is a binary(64) type and I can't seem to use the HASHBYTES function within execution of the SP

As far as the DELETE SP goes, I have not attempted it yet as I have been stuck with the UPDATE SP.

Comment: These "everything-but-the-kitchen-sink" procedures that should do **everything** inside a single procedure are typically a **really BAD idea** - it's much easier to have **three separate, focused** stored procedures - one for each task - and this also respects the widely accepted "Single Responsibility Principle"

Comment: You just provide the SP which do an INSERT, but you don't provide your attempt to create an SP for UPDATE, DELETE a table. Also does that mean the update and the delete should be in the SP? or it's 2 SPs one for UPDATE and the other for DELETE?

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the advice. I'm still learning about TSQL and SQL Server so I thought it'd be better to have everything together in one SP, turns out I was mistaken

Comment: Why can't you use the same logic for UPDATE and DELETE that you used for INSERT?    What error do you get when you try?

Comment: @Sami Sorry about that, I wasn't entirely sure where to add it because of the new system for asking a question. To answer your question, since hearing marc_s's advice, I believe it should be in 2 SPs, one for UPDATE and one for DELETE

Comment: @TabAlleman I have edited my question, I hope it somewhat answers your question

Comment: `I can't seem to use the HASHBYTES function within execution of the SP` Why not? It's just a built-in function call, like `COUNT()` or `ISNULL()`.

Comment: @digital.aaron [Does not pick it up as a value](https://imgur.com/Y3PFeRE)

Comment: On the plus side, the stored procedures you posted are good. They are SQL Injection safe (which is more than I can say about most dynamic SQL code I see on SO), and highly maintainable. Every thing I would expect from a good developer. On the other side, seems like this is code somebody else have written and you are attempting to modify it without having a clear enough understanding on what it does.  You shouldn't use `HASHBYTES` inside the procedure, the password should already be hashed when you send it to the procedure. That's why the parameter is of type `binary(64)`.

Comment: Try using a variable to hold the hashed password, and then use the variable in the proc call: `DECLARE @Hash BINARY(64) = (SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'password'))
EXEC UpdateUser_proc 'Bloemfontein', '7928623003512', 'klover', 'test.g@g.com', 'John Snow', @Hash, '20190303', 'Bloemfontein'`